# Can't do react-native run-is

Tags: react-native

My app is running fine when I run it with xcode, but when I do react-native run-ios, I get the following error:

```
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening Humboi.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace Humboi.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme Humboi -destination id=6982D224-520B-4F96-B5F6-AC7EB2C31DF5

note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
error: Could not initialize core
error: failed to load toolchain: toolchain 'com.apple.dt.toolchain.XcodeDefault' already registered from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX11.1.xctoolchain


** BUILD FAILED **
```

How to fix this?

Comment: On XCode, Preferences/Locations/Command Line Tools, make sure that you have the correct version selected

Comment: There's only one option there, 12.3